# Can't find wordpress version or updates

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to figure out if i need to update my Wordpress, but I cannot figure out what version wordpress my website is running on, nor do I have any options to update Wordpress from my admin bar. If I go to the bottom of my website in the admin area, it says "powered by Wordpress" but then there is no version printed anywhere. Clicking the footer just takes me to the reader area of my wordpress account. Searching "updates" or "version" in the search doesn't reveal anything. I am at a loss how to update and protect my site.

Cheers,
k

Comment: Sounds like you are viewing the public site, not the Admin area where this functionality is available. If you login (usually located at `yoursite.com/wp-login.php`), you will see the current version and have access to updating...if you are an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in WP Admin, under the Dashboard link on the left there is an Updates link which will shows updates available for WP Core, your plugins and your themes.

Also in the admin bar (on any front end page) there is a circle icon next with a a number next to it which will bring you to the same page